# What is the difference between clearAnimation() and stop() in android?

Tags: android, animation, animationdrawable

When I finishing my activity, should I use `clearAnimation()` or `stop()` on any remaining `AnimationDrawable` objects?

Comment: check this link [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112599/how-to-stop-animation-cancel-does-not-work

Comment: I suppose stop() means end the Animation, and the Animation still be related to the view. While clearAnimation may cancel the animation relative to the view. I haven't test it, just my guess

Answer (score 4):

`stop()` stops the animation and that's all. Since stop() is method of `AnimationDrawable.class` you can use it when you want to stop the animation of `AnimationDrawable`, but not on any View.

`clearAnimation()` is method of the `View.class`. It will stop the animation of the View and additionally:

- If there is `AnimationListener` defined, `AnimationListener.onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)` will be called.
- If there is `Handler` defined `Handler.postAtFrontOfQueue(Runnable r)` will be called.

Here is the call hierarchy:
`View.clearAnimation()` -> `Animation.detach()` -> `Animation.fireAnimationEnd()` and the `fireAnimationEnd()` method:

```
private void fireAnimationEnd() {
    if (mListener != null) {
        if (mListenerHandler == null) mListener.onAnimationEnd(this);
        else mListenerHandler.postAtFrontOfQueue(mOnEnd);
    }
}
```

Comment: I used `view.setAnimation(null)` in my case. Neither stop or clearAnimation was doing what I needed.