# Android animation blink

Tags: java, android

The code is for making a text color change evenly every 200 ms. Why is the first version change uneven/flickering, and the second one evenly changes?

```
               //first version
                long lt = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
                TextView tv = ...   
                 for (int i = 1; i < 120; i++) {
                final int cl = i % 2 == 0 ? 0xFFFF0000 : 0x00000000;
                Message w = Message.obtain(handler, new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        tv.setTextColor(cl);
                        tv.requestLayout();

                    }
                });

                handler.sendMessageDelayed(w,i * 200L - (System.currentTimeMillis()-lt));

            }

                 //second version
            Animation anim = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
            anim.setDuration(200); //You can manage the time of the blink with this parameter
            anim.setStartOffset(20);
            anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
            anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
            tv.startAnimation(anim);
```

Comment: Most likely because an `Animation` is stored, and the system knows it's going to redraw it several times, whereas a `Message` is much heavier duty and not designed for something like this.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this problem before when creating/using animations. After you are done with your animation, simply call `clearAnimation()`.

This will insure that it has fully stopped and should be nice and smooth, giving the user the experience you desire.

[How to stop an animation (cancel() does not work)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112599/how-to-stop-animation-cancel-does-not-work)

Read more:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

Regards,