# Android, how to cancel blinking animation on TextView?

Tags: android

I'm trying to enable and disable blinking animation on textview.

Start blinking works fine but stop blinking does usin:

```
anim.cancel();
anim.reset();
```

is not working and throws Null pointer exception. (But i dont know why, because variable is initialized).

How can i solve that please? Thanks for any advice.

Here is my code>

```
private Animation anim;


public void startBlinkText() {
        TextView myText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.state);
        anim = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
        anim.setDuration(200); //You can manage the time of the blink with this parameter
        anim.setStartOffset(20);
        anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
        anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        myText.startAnimation(anim);
    }

    public void stopBlinkText() {
        try {
            // TextView myText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.state);
            anim.cancel();
            anim.reset();
            // myText.startAnimation(anim);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(AppHelper.APP_LOG_NAMESPACE,
                    "stopBlinkText method cannot be processed", e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try with `textView.clearAnimation();`...

Comment: This is my real code, do you need whole activity?

Comment: When did `startBlinkText()` and `stopBlinkText()` are called ?

Comment: Your question has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112599/how-to-stop-animation-cancel-does-not-work

Comment: Sorry guys. I found what was wrong. clearAnimation method was called after the new init of the textview. If i removed the new init, problem has been solved.

Answer (score 2):

Use `clearAnimation()` to stop an animation. There is no `loadAnimation()`or `clear()` on View